# Active Server Pages returns runtime error '800a01ad'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-6

I´m running a classic asp page on IIS 6, and sometimes I get the following error when I try to create an object from a DLL:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'
>   ActiveX component can't create object

Doing my research, I have found that the problem is caused by the following reasons:

- Missing from the system
- Not in the system path
- Not accessible by the system because of security settings

I have checked those issues and everything seems to be fine. The problem is that the error is very sporadic and I can't find the conditions where it occurs. 95% of the time the application runs fine.

Comment: Which security model are you running?

Comment: btw, what ActiveX object you are trying to create?

Comment: Are you using `CreateObject` or `Server.CreateObject`?

Comment: I'm using Server.CreateObject

Comment: When the application correctly runs 95% of the time, does it successfully create the object every time at the same line in the code? Can you create a separate, simple page which repeatedly tests the createobject logic? Is the name of the object hard-coded or passed as a variable? Are you using two servers with load balancing, in which one server may be set up OK and the other not? It might help if you could post your code.

Comment: Not closing your objects in ASP can cause them to get locked and cause this problem.  You want to make sure to set your objects to NOTHING when you are done.